# K8S and Rest API

Tags: kubernetes, rest

Let's say that i have X instances of my micro service.
is there a way to send post/get requests to all instances (can scale up/down by K8s ) and verified that all instance will got the request.
for example :
let's say I have 4 instances and i have a rest API "getStatus".
now i would like to send getStatus to each one of the 4 instances and got response from all of them and somehow to aggregate the response, so the result will be:
instance 1 - good
instance 2 - good
instance 3 - not good
instance 4 - not good.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the goal/scenario you want to cover?

Answer (score 0):

You should use kubernetes liveness probe to ensure that bad pods are restarted automatically if they don't respond to the probe.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: Thanks but I think that I wasn't clear.
I have 3 pods, each service on pod has restAPI getRequestsCounter which returns a number of handled requests for this pod.
now I would like to send some request like this:
GET https://myk8s/requestCounter
now I would like to get all responses from all my alive POD:
Rersponse=
pod1 - 20 requests
pod2 - 50 requests
pod3 - ...

be aware that my cluster can scale up/down.
is there any chance to have a solution for this?

Comment: What you are looking for is  not possible with ingress. However, you may write a script to use kubectl get ep <service-name>, to get the active pod IPs and then send this in the HTTP POST Request to a new service exposed via ingress in the cluster. What this new service will do is to hit all IPs it received in the POST request and respond with their status. This service will be reachable to all the other  pod IPs for the other service as it  is  local to the cluster.